Mongo Update: Remove key and value from objects and array of objects if key contains substring
I wanted to remove key and value from objects and array of objects if key contains substring.
My sample document is
    {
    "_id": NumberLong(2761633),
    "list": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "prices": {
          "CS_1_2": "100",
          "AGE_1_2": "50",
          "AGE_2_2": "40",
          "PAC_1_2": "100"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "prices": {
          "CS_1_2": "100",
          "AGE_1_2": "50",
          "AGE_2_2": "40",
          "PAC_1_2": "100"
        }
      }
    ],
    "prices": {
      "CS_1_2": "100",
      "AGE_1_2": "50",
      "AGE_2_2": "40",
      "PAC_1_2": "100"
    }
  }

I wanted to remove all keys from prices where key contains "AGE"
I tried Like this:
{
    $set: {
      "prices": {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: {
              $objectToArray: "$prices"
            },
            cond: {
              $regexMatch: {
                input: "$$this.k",
                regex: "^(?!AGE.*)"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

This is working for top level prices object mongo_playground, but for removing from list of prices is not working with this query
Can you correct my query, Thanks

like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/RyYVeXgDjx3

you could maybe write an answer if something worked
